# Atualização de javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou desenvolvendo um contador para a Black Week. Porém, estou com uma dúvida: o contador alterará mesmo a data quando chegar dia 21? Ou é melhor criar 2 arquivos e alterar via FTP dia 21 às 0:00? (sou iniciante, por isso a dúvida)

```
<body>
<div id="dias"></div>
<div id="tempo">
    <a id="horas"></a>
    <a id="minutos"></a>
    <a id="segundos"></a>
</div>
<script>
var hoje = new Date().getDate();
var inicioBlackWeek = 20;

// Definindo a data final
if (hoje <= inicioBlackWeek)
    var contadorData = new Date("Nov 20, 2017 23:59:59").getTime();
else
    var contadorData = new Date("Nov 26, 2017 23:59:59").getTime();

// Atualizando a contagem decrescente a cada 1 segundo
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Recebendo a data e hora atual
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Encontrando a distância entre agora e a data final
    var distance = contadorData - now;

    // Cálculos de tempo por dias, horas, minutos e segundos
    var dias = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var horas = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutos = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var segundos = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Retornando resultados
    if (hoje <= inicioBlackWeek) {
        document.getElementById("dias").innerHTML = "<font style = 'color: red;'>Faltam apenas<br /><font style = 'font-size: 100pt'>" + dias + " dias</font></font>";
        document.getElementById("segundos").innerHTML = +segundos + "s<br /><font style = 'font-size 50pt'>para a Black Week!</font>";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("dias").innerHTML = "<font style = 'color: red;'>Restam apenas<br /><font style = 'font-size: 100pt'>" + dias + " dias</font></font>";
        document.getElementById("segundos").innerHTML = +segundos + "s<br /><font style = 'font-size 50pt'>de Black Week!</font>";
    }


    document.getElementById("horas").innerHTML = "e " + horas + "h ";
    document.getElementById("minutos").innerHTML = +minutos + "m ";


    // Se a contagem decrescente terminar, mudará a escrita das divs
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("dias").innerHTML = "<font style = 'color: red'>FINALIZADO</font>";
        document.getElementById("tempo").innerHTML = "";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67952/discussion-on-question-by-joao-pedro-atualizacao-de-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Sua pergunta `O contador alterará mesmo a data quando chegar dia 21?`

Minha resposta  `Com certeza o contador vai alterar a data no dia 21.`

Para verificar é muito simples, basta supor `var hoje=21;`, veja

```js
//supondo hoje ser dia 21
    var hoje=21;
    var inicioBlackWeek = 20;

    // Definindo a data final
    if (hoje <= inicioBlackWeek){

        var contadorData = new Date("Nov 20, 2017 23:59:59").getTime();
        //supondo hoje ser antes do dia 20
        console.log("hoje dia 19 contadorData => Nov 20, 2017 23:59:59");
        
    }else{

        var contadorData = new Date("Nov 26, 2017 23:59:59").getTime();
        //supondo hoje ser dia 21
        console.log("hoje dia 21 contadorData => Nov 26, 2017 23:59:59");
        
    }
```

### Utilizando o código inteiro

Par verificar é muito simples:

faça a `var hoje` igual a 21.

```
var hoje = 21;
```

altere essa linha `var distance = contadorData - now;`

para  `var distance = contadorData - (now+(86400*(hoje-new Date().getDate())*1000));`

> Se a variável `var hoje` é igual a 21 e a diferença entre `var hoje` e a variável  `var contadorData` der 5 dias é que houve a tal mudança que você duvidou se iria mudar.
>
> Com essa alteração você vai constatar que o texto `Faltam apenas` mudará para  `Restam apenas` que é a condição else da verificação if (hoje <= inicioBlackWeek) {

Veja funcionando.

```js
var hoje = new Date().getDate();

 //para que após o dia 21 de novembro não seja necessário mudar para 22, 23 etc...
 var mes = (new Date().getMonth())+1;
 if (mes==10 || hoje<21){
  hoje = 21;
 }
 
 
 var inicioBlackWeek = 20;
 
 // Definindo a data final
 if (hoje <= inicioBlackWeek)
 var contadorData = new Date("Nov 20, 2017 23:59:59").getTime();
 else
 var contadorData = new Date("Nov 26, 2017 23:59:59").getTime();
 
 // Atualizando a contagem decrescente a cada 1 segundo
 var x = setInterval(function() {
 
 // Recebendo a data e hora atual
 var now = new Date().getTime();
 
 // Encontrando a distância entre agora e a data final
 var distance = contadorData - (now+(86400*(hoje-new Date().getDate())*1000));
 
 // Cálculos de tempo por dias, horas, minutos e segundos
 var dias = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
 var horas = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
 var minutos = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
 var segundos = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
 
 // Retornando resultados
 if (hoje <= inicioBlackWeek) {
     document.getElementById("dias").innerHTML = "<font style = 'color: red;'>Faltam apenas<br /><font style = 'font-size: 100pt'>" + dias + " dias</font></font>";
     document.getElementById("segundos").innerHTML = +segundos + "s<br /><font style = 'font-size 50pt'>para a Black Week!</font>";
 } else {
     document.getElementById("dias").innerHTML = "<font style = 'color: red;'>Restam apenas<br /><font style = 'font-size: 100pt'>" + dias + " dias</font></font>";
     document.getElementById("segundos").innerHTML = +segundos + "s<br /><font style = 'font-size 50pt'>de Black Week!</font>";
 }
 
 
 document.getElementById("horas").innerHTML = "e " + horas + "h ";
 document.getElementById("minutos").innerHTML = +minutos + "m ";
 
 
 // Se a contagem decrescente terminar, mudará a escrita das divs
 if (distance < 0) {
     clearInterval(x);
     document.getElementById("dias").innerHTML = "<font style = 'color: red'>FINALIZADO</font>";
     document.getElementById("tempo").innerHTML = "";
 }
 }, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="dias"></div>
<div id="tempo">
    <a id="horas"></a>
    <a id="minutos"></a>
    <a id="segundos"></a>
</div>
```

> Desnecessário explicar que até 21/11 sempre vão faltar 5 dias.